# Language Dropdown missing in Listview/ Objectview (Typo3 11)

Tags: listview, typo3

I recently updated my TYPO3 CMS from version 9 to version 11 and I’ve encountered an issue with the localization dropdown in the list view. In TYPO3 v9, when I was in the list view (in an Event), I could see a localization dropdown at the top that allowed me to switch between different languages. However, after updating to TYPO3 v11, this dropdown is no longer visible. The only options I see under Localization are “Standard” or nothing.

[Typo3 9](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ifd8Z.png)
[Typo3 11](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3HXau.png)

My TCA:

```
   [ 'sys_language_uid' => [
            'exclude' => true,
            'label' => 'LLL:EXT:core/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_general.xlf:LGL.language',
            'config' => [
                'type' => 'language',
            ],
        ],
        'l10n_parent' => [
            'displayCond' => 'FIELD:sys_language_uid:>:0',
            'exclude' => true,
            'label' => 'LLL:EXT:core/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_general.xlf:LGL.l18n_parent',
            'config' => [
                'type' => 'select',
                'renderType' => 'selectSingle',
                'default' => 0,
                'items' => [
                    ['', 0],
                ],
                'foreign_table' => 'tx_events_domain_model_events',
                'foreign_table_where' => 'AND {#tx_tevents_domain_model_events}.{#pid}=###CURRENT_PID### AND {#tx_events_domain_model_events}.{#sys_language_uid} IN (-1,0)',
            ],
        ],
        'l10n_diffsource' => [
            'config' => [
                'type' => 'passthrough',
            ],
        ],
    ]
```

Comment: You have configured the available languages properly in SiteConfiguration? IMO `sys_languages`-table has been dying slowly (and was finally removed now).

Comment: Are you sure that this is about the "list view" at all? Your Screenshots both show the opened editing form of a specific record, not a list. And the TYPO3-11 screenshot actually shows the dropdown, while the TYPO3-9 screenshot does not.

Comment: I have mixed up the picture headings. Yes a specific Record i opened via the List view. The siteconfig is correctly configured with two languages, but there is only one in the sys_language table.
The correct language is also not displayed in the list view under "Localization", it either says nothing or standard.

Answer (score 0):

Just checked that with a default CMS 11 and the only option you've got to have the language switch removed is that you are trying to translate a record on page which is not translated itself.

You always have to translate pages - even pages configured as folders - to all desired target languages first, before you will be able to translate any record on that page.